# ServiceStack - How to Deserialize DateTime which could be in multiple formats per each request without overriding global defaults

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, servicestack

I have some global defaults

```
JsConfig.DateHandler = DateHandler.ISO8601;
JsConfig.AlwaysUseUtc = true;
JsConfig.AssumeUtc = true;
```

I am reading CsvFiles which have date fields that are in multiple formats and are not supported by the global defaults. I have resolved this by the following code

```
var fn = JsConfig<DateTime?>.DeSerializeFn;
try
{
    using (var fs = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
    {
        var formats = new[]
        {
            "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        };

        JsConfig<DateTime?>.DeSerializeFn = str =>
        {
            if (str == null) return null;
            return DateTime.ParseExact(str, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
        };

        return CsvSerializer.DeserializeFromStream<List<T>>(fs);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw new FileLoadException(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
    JsConfig<DateTime?>.DeSerializeFn = fn;
}
```

Now the problem I have is that this breaks the application everywhere else whilst the parser is in line 2 and just before the final line. This is because I grab the original settings, change it for what I need then change it back in the finally. JsConfig.With does not work as their isn't a DateTimeFormat array property, what else can I do? I am stumped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot "temporarily" change the serialization implementation for any Type, i.e. what ever custom implementation you register must remain immutable thereafter.

Either your custom implementation needs to support every format you want to use, change to deserialize into a `string` so you can apply your own custom implementation to the original string after it's deserialized, or you need to use a different serializer to use a custom implementation.